# Текст с автоматическим отступом и по центру

Tags: html, css

Есть код:

```
<div style="background: #000; width: 100px; height: 30px; color: #fff; text-align: center">text</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы слово text отступало сверху и стояло ровно по середине. padding **не предлагать**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант добавить `line-height: 1.8`

```
<div style="background: #000; width: 100px; height: 30px; color: #fff; text-align: center; line-height: 1.8">text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, использовать

`position:relative`

и

`top:-...px`

Или же просто отрицательный мергин.

Answer (score 1):

`line-height:` должно быть равно высоте твоего блока, то есть `30px`.

Answer (score 1):

display:table-cell;

vertical-align:middle;